# What are "Legacy brushes"?

Tags: uwp

On Windows 10, the `generic.xaml` file for UWP apps is available for reference in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.x.0\Generic` folder, where `x` refers to the installed SDKs' versions.  Within this file, I've come across a list of `SolidColorBrush` resources labeled "Legacy brushes".

What exactly does "legacy brush" mean?  This term doesn't appear to be defined in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of these are the 'original' WinRT system brushes (hence 'legacy') so they help support migration of Windows 8.1 and phone apps to UWP, see [w8x-to-uwp-porting-xaml-and-ui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-porting-xaml-and-ui#resource-keys-and-textblock-style-sizes) for additional information. But, this doesn't imply that they are not also currently being used in UWP, as you can see by looking in "[styles and themes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210949.aspx)" where these 'legacy' brushes are still being used.